# Поле мемо С++

Tags: c++

Искал в интернете, но как работать с числами в мемо так и не нашёл...Если можно то, пожалуйста, распишете, какая строчка что делает.

1. Ввести с клавиатуры текстовую строку, состоящую из нескольких целых чисел, разделяемых пробелами.
2. Динамически зарезервировать память под целочисленный массив хранения этих чисел.
3. Сформировать упомянутый массив.
4. Выполнить сортировку массива по возрастанию методом «пузырька», предварительно разработать структурную схему алгоритма сортировки.
5. Вывести на экран исходный и отсортированный массивы.

Comment: Думаю, решение нужно искать не в интернете, а в собственных мозгах. поищите, может, получится.

Comment: Я понимаю,просто учусь в университете и мемо мы ещё не проходили на лекциях,но я вырвался вперёд по лабам т к основы С++ более менее знал,а если не знал то активно юзал гугл..К сожалению в школе мемо мы не проходили по этому искать что либо в мозгах,по этому поводу,нет смысла.А в гугле не нашёл ничего стоящего.Решил написать сюда,если не получится тут,чтож буду ждать лекцию.

Comment: Сложность может быть только в разборе строки на числа - гугл юзинг и проблема решена)

Comment: "мемо" - это что такое ? 

А по пунктам схема очевидна.

    char str[1024]; 
    if (!fgets(str,1024,stdin) {
        printf("Eof\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int size, 
        int *srcarr = makearray(str,&size);
    if (!srcarr) { 
        printf ("No data\n"); 
        exit(2); 
    }
    int *srtarr = sortcopy(srcarr,size);
    printarr("Source array",srcarr,size);
    printarr("Sorted array",srtarr,size);
    free(srtarr); free(srcarr); 
    exit(0);

В makearray() и sortcopy() динамически выделяется память. Напишите их сами. Сколько выделять, догадаетесь ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашел свою реализацию подобного на Builder 6.0. Единственное, что здесь работа не с мемо, а с листбоксом! Меняете строки типа:

```
ListBox1->Items->Add(IntToStr(A[i]));
```

на строки типа:

```
Form1->Memo3->Lines->Add("выводим A[i]="+IntToStr(A[i]));
```

то есть отличие в Lines и в том, что нужно применить функцию IntToStr(этого вам должно хватить).

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
int i,t,j;
long int A[3500];
int min,min_p;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::N2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(i=0;i<3500;i++)
    {A[i]=random(100);
        ListBox1->Items->Add(IntToStr(A[i]));
    }
    ShowMessage("Масив из случайных чисел успешно сформирован!!!");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::N3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(long int x=3500;x>0;x--)
    {for(i=0;i<3500-1;i++)
        {if(A[i]>A[i+1])
            {t=A[i];
                A[i]=A[i+1];
                A[i+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3500;i++)
    ListBox2->Items->Add(IntToStr(A[i]));
    ShowMessage("Сортировка масива из случайных чисел методом Пузырька прошел успешно!!!");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::N4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i,j,min,pos,temp;
    {for(i=0;i<3500-1;i++)
        {min=A[i];
            pos=i;
            for(j=i+1;i<3500;i++)
            if(A[j]<min)
            {min=A[j];
                pos=j;
            }
            temp=A[i];
            A[i]=A[pos];
            A[pos]=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<3500;i++)
        ListBox3->Items->Add(IntToStr(A[i]));
    }
    ShowMessage("Сортировка масива из случайных чисел методом Выбора прошел успешно!!!");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::N5Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    exit(1);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------</pre>
```

Comment: Благодарю,сейчас буду разбираться=)